# G33kDude cJson - After loading Json string into AHK, how to access a key via AHK notation?

Tags: autohotkey

I have the following `json` file and want to turn it into an AHK object:

```
{
    "folders": [
        {
            "path": "."
        }
    ],
    "settings": {
            "files.exclude": {
            "**/.git": true,
            "**/.svn": true,
            "**/.hg": true,
            "**/CVS": true,
            "**/.DS_Store": true,
            "**/Thumbs.db": true,
            "**.lnk":true,
            "*.code-workspace" :true,
            "**.vscode/":true,
            "**.url":true
        },
        "terminal.integrated.fontSize": 12,
    }
}
```

I only care for the key `terminal.integrated.fontSize` and its value `12`. I want to increment/decrement it and save it back by overwriting the file.

I have tried the following, I am stuck at getting the value `terminal.integrated.fontSize`, the debugger shows `Object {["files.exclude"]: Object, ["terminal.integrated.fontSize"]: 12}` but `OutPutDebug` just prints nothing:

```
path    := "C:\temp\Rest APIs.code-workspace"
Obj     := Json.Load(FileOpen(Path,"r").Read())
OutputDebug, % Obj.settings
OutputDebug, % Obj.settings[1]
OutputDebug, % Obj.settings[2]
```

If you want to know what I am doing, I explain it here,  [How to increase the value of a setting in 'Settings.json' with a hotkey?](https://superuser.com/questions/1809452/how-to-increase-the-value-of-a-setting-in-settings-json-with-a-hotkey)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, your JSON code is incorrect.
I typically use [THIS](https://jsonlint.com/) website to validate JSON input before working on it.
In your JSON code, there is a comma after "12" that shouldn't be there.

With that clarified, here are some ways to achieve what you want using the same library you are using.

```
j   =
    (
        {
            "folders": [{
                "path": "."
            }],
            "settings": {
                "files.exclude": {
                    "**/.git": true,
                    "**/.svn": true,
                    "**/.hg": true,
                    "**/CVS": true,
                    "**/.DS_Store": true,
                    "**/Thumbs.db": true,
                    "**.lnk": true,
                    "*.code-workspace": true,
                    "**.vscode/": true,
                    "**.url": true
                },
                "terminal.integrated.fontSize": 12
            }
        }
    )
obj := json.load(j)
    OutputDebug, % obj.settings["terminal.integrated.fontSize"]

obj.settings["terminal.integrated.fontSize"] := 15
    OutputDebug, % obj.settings["terminal.integrated.fontSize"]

obj.settings["terminal.integrated.fontSize"]++
    OutputDebug, % obj.settings["terminal.integrated.fontSize"]

new_json := json.dump(obj)
Msgbox % new_json
ExitApp, 0
```

Comment: Thank yo for that, really appreciate it.